# Host Performance

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise, powershell-core

```
param(
    $path = "C:\test"
)cls

(Measure-Command{
#
$s = [Text.StringBuilder]::new()
for($i=1; $i -le 1000; $i++){
    $s.AppendLine("[$i] Str")
    [IO.File]::WriteAllText("$path\file_$i.txt", $s)
}
#
}).TotalMilliseconds
```

- Powershell.exe - 150
- Powershell_ISE.exe - 2600
- Pwsh.exe(7.1) - 3200

Everybody have the same results, or there is something wrong with my ISE and pscore?

Comment: Did you only run it _once_? And is `$st` a typo?

Comment: as @MathiasR.Jessen pointed out, you have two problems with your code. [1] the `$st` means you are writing nothing to your file. [2] you only ran the code once - and PoSh tends to be rather variable speed-wise. you need to run the code MANY times to get a realistic estimate of how fast it would run. for instance, your code gives me 440ms, 300ms, 380ms, and 350ms when i run it in the ISE.

Comment: On top of PowerShell being "variable speed-wise" (or "jittery" if you will), PowerShell also has many layers of runtime abstraction, including a great deal of caching layers - first time a function or scriptblock is run it needs to be parsed, analyzed and compiled before it can execute, so the very first time a function/cmdlet/scripblock is invoked will always carry a large amount of overhead compared to subsequent invocations

Comment: $st - of course $s. Typo. I've run this several times. Given results - are best of many runs.

Comment: This is not just about PowerShell, but your overall host environment impacts. RAM (amount and speed), CPU (number and speed), other stuff running on your machine. Everyone will get different numbers. For example, on one of my lab systems, using the Win10 `a default Windows Sandbox VM`, ISE = between `846 and 958`, in the console host, between `854 and 1038`. The numbers of course are completely different others.

Comment: I get quite similar results between all PS executables (about 3100 ms). Only first run was slower, for the reasons explained by other commenters. More than 20x performance difference between Powershell.exe and Pwsh.exe in your case seems odd, if this happens even for repeated runs.

Comment: I refactored your code a bit ( I can post that if you want it), to hit all three hosts and run 9 times in each. So those numbers at the low and high from the passes. Using this same code, on a heavy developer box, the numbers for way up. `4697 and 6019`.